# Using Case When in SQL to return different values

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to join various table and convert some column values from integer to text like below case. Let's say I have `Type_ID: 1, 2, 100, 200, 300, .....`

If the Type_ID are 1 and 200, then it will print out High and Good respectively. But if the Type_ID are not 1 and 200, I want it to return original integer value. How can I do that? Thanks.

```
SELECT A.AID, 
CASE WHEN B.Type_ID = '1' THEN 'High' WHEN B.Type_ID = '200' THEN 'GOOD' ELSE (Print Original number value) END AS 'Type'
FROM A, B
WHERE A.AID = B.AID
```

Expected Result:

| AID | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | High |
| 2 | 499 |
| 3 | Good |
| 4 | Good |
| 5 | 100 |
| 6 | 300 |

Comment: What do you have in table A and table B? Please provide example data.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the else value should just be the `Type_ID`:

```sql
SELECT A.AID, 
       CASE B.Type_ID WHEN '1' THEN 'High'
                      WHEN '200' THEN 'GOOD'
                      ELSE CAST(B.Type_ID AS CHAR(50)) END AS Type
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.AID = B.AID;
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried using this but this error prompt: Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

Comment: I'm surprised by this error on MySQL, but in any case have a look at the update above.